# How do I store continuous variables efficiently in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, optimization, indexing, query-optimization

I am familiar to how indexing works in sql, but to my understanding indexing does not work well with continuous variables (like latitude/longitude, prices, time, etc.).

I can think of a couple hypothetical ways to make searching for continuous columns faster, by either clustering them by ranges or storing them sorted and then doing a binary search on them. However, I don't know if sql supports these methods.

1. Do my proposed methods actually exist in sql?
2. Is there another faster solution to storing and searching continuous variables?

Answer (score 1):

Indexing works fine on continuous variables, and it implements it in a similar way to how you propose. The indices are stored in a B+ Tree, and the leaves of the tree are in order. So if you do range queries, they run very quickly as it can scan sequentially through the leaves of the tree.

There are various ways that you can tell SQL to implement this to get performance improvements, but the default works pretty well in most cases.

The Lat/Long is a different story, because you are querying on two dimensions. For example
you might ask for all stores within 100 mi of a particular lat/lon.  These types of fields are best stored in an R tree. Most RDBMS implement this in addition to B+ trees.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on the type of query you want to optimize.

Let's suppose you always want to  `SELECT ... ORDER BY price` a table that is mostly constant : you may use `ALTER TABLE ... ORDER BY col` to help ordering (ie reduce time) for subsequent queries.